# Detection of NVIDIA GTX860M graphics card in Manjaro Linux?

Tags: drivers, nvidia, manjaro, proprietary-drivers

When I ran device query, I got this error:

```
./deviceQuery Starting...

 CUDA Device Query (Runtime API) version (CUDART static linking)

NVIDIA: no NVIDIA devices found
cudaGetDeviceCount returned 30
-> unknown error
Result = FAI
```

However, I have already installed the best proprietary driver out there for this graphic card via mhwd (Manjaro hardware detection), so basically I got the bumblebee hybrid card "video-hybrid-intel-nvidia-bumblebee"

But despite installing the appropriate driver, the card doesn't get detected. Why?

I ran inxi -G which gives:

```
Graphics:  Card-1: Intel 4th Gen Core Processor Integrated Graphics Controller
           Card-2: NVIDIA GM107M [GeForce GTX 860M]
           Display Server: X.Org 1.17.4 driver: intel Resolution: 1920x1080
           GLX Renderer: Mesa DRI Intel Haswell Mobile GLX Version: 3.0 Mesa 12.0.1
```

Thank you so much for your help.

Comment: This question is now two years old. Did you manage to solve this issue [using the non-free drivers](https://wiki.manjaro.org/index.php?title=Configure_NVIDIA_(non-free)_settings_and_load_them_on_Startup)?